# Missing features in Visual Studios Community 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am new to using Visual Studios Community. I am currently working out of a book called "Head First C#".

The problem is that I cannot find some features that are in the book, such as "Windows Store" (which the book says should be a subcategory under "Visual C#" when one wants to create a new project) or "Basic Page".

Have these features been discontinued? Or do I have to modify my installation in someway using the VS installer?

I am using Visual Studios Community 2017 on a Windows 10 OS.

Comment: It is not gone, just renamed.  Now labeled "Universal", aka WinRT v1.4  Windows 8.x users were expected to take advantage of the free Win10 update.  Phone is dead.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2017 community supports UWP development.   Open the visual studio installer and select modify.  There is an update available install that before trying to modify.  Make sure the Universal Windows Platform Development workflow is checked and press the update button.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/get-set-up